# Android: Saving Bitmap to external storage fails

Tags: java, android, io, bitmap, android-external-storage

I am having trouble saving a bitmap to external storage.

I tried saving a txt file as well and that did not work either.

My bitmap code follows:

```
//filename ends with .png
private void SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
//Get Pictures folder
    File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
//Create new folder and mkdir it if it does not exist.
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/ReCorder");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File (dir, fileName);
    try {                                                             
//Make sure file exists   
        if (!file.exists()) {
             file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This does not work:
When I run it, I get (at the line file.createNewFile();):

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

When I remove the file.createNewFile(); line, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ReCorder/test.png
```

I also made sure I have the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For debugging I use the in AndroidStudio integrated Emulator for the Nexus 5X.

I would greatly appreciate your help with my problem. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you grant realtime permission?

Comment: You don't have pemission. Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: Thank you! Didn´t know I had to ask for permission again.